# What enclosure do I need so I can connect this to my pc via usb

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

I'm looking to connect this to my mac in order to get files off of it. What can I use to do that?

[SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vKPR.jpg)

I have this: [What i've got](https://www.pbtech.co.nz/product/ENCUNI0033/Unitek-Y-3365-USB30-M2-SSD-External-Enclosure-Supp) but it doesn't seem right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The M.2 socket is complicated. The socket could be running SATA or PCI-Express (NVMe), and they are not inter-changeable.

Your SSD is an M.2 socket, B+M-Key, SATA drive.

The specs on your [Unitek Y-3365](https://www.unitek-products.com/products/usb3-0-m-2-ssd-ngff-sata-aluminium-enclosure) enclosure does mention SATA, and support for B+M-Key M.2 SSD's. I expect it would work just fine.